# Why fish shell does not allow function named `-`

Tags: shell, fish, bash-alias

I am trying to use fish as my default interactive shell. I was previously using bash and there was support for alias named `-` (ASCII hyphen, 0x2d). Why does not fish allow creation of alias or function with such name? As far as I know, it has no special meaning in fish.

Bash-like invocation of `alias` is not possible:

```
fish-3.1.2$ alias -- -='aliased command'
- (line 1): function: Illegal function name '-'
function - --wraps 'aliased command' --description 'alias -=aliased command';  aliased command $argv; end
^
from sourcing file -
        called on line 61 of file /usr/share/fish/functions/alias.fish
in function 'alias' with arguments '-- -=aliased\ command'
```

Comment: Have you tried `alias -- -='some command'`? Note not all shells support hyphens. See [bash - Are there problems with hyphens in functions, aliases, and executables? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168221/are-there-problems-with-hyphens-in-functions-aliases-and-executables)
`

Comment: @DavidPostill, Yes I have already tried to do that – it does not work (fish aliases are implemented as functions).

Comment: This does not answer "why", but: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#shell-variable-and-function-names

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are just a wrapper around fish functions, so I can confirm in Fish 3.3.1 (current version as of this post), this won't work:

```
function -
   echo "here"
end
fish: function: Illegal function name '-'
```

However, there's a simple workaround by using abbr (abbreviations):

```
abbr -a -- - 'cd -'
```

In case it's unclear what this is doing with all the dashes, the double dash "--" separates ambiguous command options from arguments so that the following dash "-" is recognized as the name of the abbr, and not interpreted as another option like "-a".

In many ways, abbreviations are better than aliases anyway, as they don't mask the real command you executed in your history, and setting up a lot of aliases in your fish.conf is slow, as all those aliases get eval-ed to functions anyway, but don't get the benefit of being lazy loaded. [The fish docs also confirm abbr is the way](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#how-can-i-use-as-a-shortcut-for-cd).

Answer (score 1):

I went digging in the history, and it looks like this was introduced in [320cb6857f](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/320cb6857f2b8c44e2caf76553ae931a15e10e81) to fix an issue where function names starting with `-` were interpreted as arguments. Functions starting with `-` didn't actually work, but this change made it explicit.